# System.OutOfMemoryException while downloading a lot of attachments with MailKit

Tags: out-of-memory, attachment, mailkit

I'm downloading attachments from few e-mail accounts. I have for example 300 attachments on each account (they are mirrors). When I want download attachments only from one account, I get error in my program log:

```
...
09.04.2017 16:10:07: Download attachment nr 108 from task Movie.avi
09.04.2017 16:10:59: Download attachment nr 109 from task Movie.avi
09.04.2017 16:11:26: Download attachment nr 110 from task Movie.avi
09.04.2017 16:12:07: Download attachment nr 111 from task Movie.avi
09.04.2017 16:12:34: Download attachment nr 112 from task Movie.avi
09.04.2017 16:13:07: Download attachment nr 113 from task Movie.avi
09.04.2017 16:13:55: Download attachment nr 114 from task Movie.avi
09.04.2017 16:14:03: System.OutOfMemoryException: Zgłoszono wyjątek typu 'System.OutOfMemoryException'.
   w MimeKit.IO.MemoryBlockStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapFolder.FetchStream(ImapEngine engine, ImapCommand ic, Int32 index)
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapEngine.ProcessUntaggedResponse(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapCommand.Step()
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapEngine.Iterate()
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapEngine.Wait(ImapCommand ic)
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapFolder.GetMessage(UniqueId uid, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ITransferProgress progress)
   w MailExchange.Form1.makeDownload(String nazwa) w c:\Users\DamianOS.MP5\Documents\mailexchange\MailExchange\Form1.cs:wiersz 1086
09.04.2017 16:14:47: System.OutOfMemoryException: Zgłoszono wyjątek typu 'System.OutOfMemoryException'.
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapStream.ReadQuotedStringToken(Byte* inbuf, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapStream.ReadToken(String specials, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapStream.ReadToken(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapUtils.ParseEnvelopeAddress(ImapEngine engine, String format, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapUtils.ParseEnvelopeAddressList(InternetAddressList list, ImapEngine engine, String format, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapUtils.ParseEnvelope(ImapEngine engine, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapFolder.FetchSummaryItems(ImapEngine engine, ImapCommand ic, Int32 index)
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapEngine.ProcessUntaggedResponse(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapCommand.Step()
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapEngine.Iterate()
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapEngine.Wait(ImapCommand ic)
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapFolder.Fetch(Int32 min, Int32 max, MessageSummaryItems items, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   w MailExchange.Form1.makeDownload(String nazwa) w c:\Users\DamianOS.MP5\Documents\mailexchange\MailExchange\Form1.cs:wiersz 1041
09.04.2017 16:15:04: System.OutOfMemoryException: Zgłoszono wyjątek typu 'System.OutOfMemoryException'.
   w System.Text.StringBuilder..ctor(String value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Int32 capacity)
   w MimeKit.Utils.ParseUtils.TryParseDotAtom(Byte[] text, Int32& index, Int32 endIndex, Byte[] sentinels, Boolean throwOnError, String tokenType, String& dotatom)
   w MimeKit.InternetAddress.TryParseAddrspec(Byte[] text, Int32& index, Int32 endIndex, Byte[] sentinels, Boolean throwOnError, String& addrspec)
   w MimeKit.InternetAddress.TryParseMailbox(ParserOptions options, Byte[] text, Int32 startIndex, Int32& index, Int32 endIndex, String name, Int32 codepage, Boolean throwOnError, InternetAddress& address)
   w MimeKit.InternetAddress.TryParse(ParserOptions options, Byte[] text, Int32& index, Int32 endIndex, AddressParserFlags flags, InternetAddress& address)
   w MimeKit.InternetAddressList.TryParse(ParserOptions options, Byte[] text, Int32& index, Int32 endIndex, Boolean isGroup, Boolean throwOnError, List`1& addresses)
   w MimeKit.MimeMessage.AddAddresses(Header header, InternetAddressList list)
   w MimeKit.MimeMessage.HeadersChanged(Object o, HeaderListChangedEventArgs e)
   w MimeKit.HeaderList.OnChanged(Header header, HeaderListChangedAction action)
   w MimeKit.HeaderList.Add(Header header)
   w MimeKit.MimeMessage..ctor(ParserOptions options, IEnumerable`1 headers)
   w MimeKit.MimeParser.ParseMessage(Byte* inbuf)
   w MimeKit.MimeParser.ParseMessage(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   w MailKit.Net.Pop3.Pop3Client.DownloadHeaderContext.Parse(Pop3Stream data, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   w MailKit.Net.Pop3.Pop3Client.DownloadContext`1.OnDataReceived(Pop3Engine pop3, Pop3Command pc, String text)
   w MailKit.Net.Pop3.Pop3Engine.ReadResponse(Pop3Command pc)
   w MailKit.Net.Pop3.Pop3Engine.Iterate()
   w MailKit.Net.Pop3.Pop3Client.DownloadContext`1.DownloadItem(Int32 seqid, Boolean headersOnly, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   w MailKit.Net.Pop3.Pop3Client.GetMessageHeaders(Int32 index, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   w MailExchange.Form1.makeDownload(String nazwa) w c:\Users\DamianOS.MP5\Documents\mailexchange\MailExchange\Form1.cs:wiersz 1053
```

When I'm downloading for example 100 attachments from first account, 100 attachments from second account and 100 from third account, everything is ok. But I want download 300 attachments from one account. Lines with errors:

```
//1086 line:
readyMessages.Add(client.Inbox.GetMessage(imapReadySubjects[posortowanaLista[i]].UniqueId, cancellationToken, progress));
//1041 line:
IList<IMessageSummary> allMailList = client.Inbox.Fetch(0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId, cancellationToken);
//1053 line:
for (int i = 0; i < client2.Count; i++)
    allMailLists.Add(client2.GetMessageHeaders(i), i);
```

Full code from file:
https://bitbucket.org/DamianOS_MP5/mailexchange/src/3af44d3ffa7e61fb40afbcb7d75fefd068b80ff6/MailExchange/Form1.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: Can you provide more info?  Your question is not very clear.  Are you asking why the larger download batch might be a problem and how you might fix it?  Are you asking something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are keeping hundreds of messages in a `List`.

Solution: Don't do that.

Why do you need the `readyMessages` list at all? You only ever access the last element in the list (which is the most recently downloaded message).