# System.OutOfMemoryException while sending a lot of messages with attachments using MailKit

Tags: out-of-memory, attachment, mailkit

I'm sending a lot of messages with big attachments (20 MB - 50 MB) with MailKit. When my application works long time (~4h) and sends these messages, RAM usage is growing and at one point program is unexpectedly closed without any error message. Some user sent me info from his log (it's interesting why on his computer program was not closed?):

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Zgłoszono wyjątek typu
>   'System.OutOfMemoryException'. w
>   MimeKit.IO.MemoryBlockStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   count) w MimeKit.AttachmentCollection.LoadContent(MimePart attachment,
>   Stream stream) w
>   MimeKit.AttachmentCollection.CreateAttachment(ContentType contentType,
>   String fileName, Stream stream) w
>   MimeKit.AttachmentCollection.Add(String fileName) w
>   MailExchange.Form1.makeSend(String nazwa) w
>   c:\Users\DamianOS.MP5\Documents\mailexchange\MailExchange\Form1.cs:**line
>   587**

Here is source file (lines match): https://bitbucket.org/DamianOS_MP5/mailexchange/src/117df6fef0628e13c5ded35e234e06f3852b95f3/MailExchange/Form1.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

I know that's my fault. I asked a similar question here: [System.OutOfMemoryException while downloading a lot of attachments with MailKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43309110/system-outofmemoryexception-while-downloading-a-lot-of-attachments-with-mailkit) and there problem has been solved. But here situation is a little different.

I will be really grateful for the advice.

Screens from JetBrains dotMemory:
[image: First screen]
[image: Second screen]

Answer (score 0):

You're running out of memory because you are adding things to lists in your program that only ever grow and grow and grow.

Don't do that.

Comment: OK but which list? `builder = null; zalacznik = null; message = null;` after each sended message give no result :(

Comment: your lists still grow, even if all of their elements are set to null.

Comment: Just because you get the OutOfMemoryException in the makeSend() method doesn't mean that's where the leak has to be. You have tons of other lists in your code that never get cleaned up.

Comment: After a week I found an error. Now it is working correct :)